# How to remove the border of an Infragistics Composite Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, infragistics

Does anyone know how to remove the black borders on this Composite Chart (Infragistics Winforms 2018.1)?

[image: Sample]

I tried everything and nothing works:

```cs
this.Curva.Border.Color = Color.Transparent;
this.Curva.CompositeChart.ChartAreas[0].Border.Color = Color.Transparent;
columnLayer.ChartArea.Border.Thickness = 0;
```

Comment: *When using this tag add also a tag that narrows your question to scope the question to the appropriate experts in the field.* - see the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/infragistics/info)

Comment: @MarcoAntonio: Seems like you are pointing to the X/Y axes. Do you want to hide the X/Y axes?

Comment: No, I just want to remove the black borders

Comment: @MarcoAntonio: Can you show line of code where you are adding `xAxis` to the `ChartArea`, please?

Comment: xAxisLine.DataType = AxisDataType.String;
xAxisLine.SetLabelAxisType = SetLabelAxisType.ContinuousData;
xAxisLine.Labels.Visible = false;

area.Axes.Add(xAxisColumn);
area.Axes.Add(xAxisLine);

Answer (score 0):

Jackdaw, see:

```
AxisItem xAxisColumn = new AxisItem(this.Curva, AxisNumber.X_Axis);
AxisItem xAxisLine = new AxisItem(this.Curva, AxisNumber.X_Axis);

xAxisColumn.DataType = AxisDataType.String;
xAxisColumn.SetLabelAxisType = SetLabelAxisType.GroupBySeries;
xAxisColumn.Labels.ItemFormat = AxisItemLabelFormat.Custom;
xAxisColumn.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
xAxisColumn.Labels.SeriesLabels.Orientation = TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing;
xAxisColumn.Labels.SeriesLabels.FormatString = "<SERIES_LABEL: ##.##>";

xAxisLine.DataType = AxisDataType.String;
xAxisLine.SetLabelAxisType = SetLabelAxisType.ContinuousData;
xAxisLine.Labels.Visible = false;

area.Axes.Add(xAxisColumn);
area.Axes.Add(xAxisLine);
```